# importing python module from outside the package produce unexpected behavior

Tags: python, python-module

Let's say I have such a directory structure:

```
 - Documents/
   - thesis_program/
     - __init__.py
     - classes.py
     - utils.py
     - GE_Test.py
   - GE_Test_fail.py
```

classes.py and utils.py contains some classes and functions.
GE_Test.py and GE_Test_fail.py contains the exactly same code, except the import part.
In **GE_Test.py** I import classes and utils this way:

```
from utils import execute
from classes import Grammatical_Evolution
```

While in **GE_Test_fail.py**, I import classes and utils this way:

```
from thesis_program.utils import execute
from thesis_program.classes import Grammatical_Evolution
```

And unexpectedly I get a different result. Is there anything wrong here?
Do I import the modules correctly?

I can ensure that the result should be the same, because I generate the random number with certain seed

Also classes.py is somehow depended on utils.py since I have several common functions in utils.py. I suspect that utils is also a name used by the system. So in the second case (GE_Test_fail.py) The system utils override my utils.py. But it doesn't seem make sense for me.

The complete source code of classes.py and utils.py is available here (if it helps to discover what's wrong): https://github.com/goFrendiAsgard/feature-extractor

And also, the screenshots: https://picasaweb.google.com/111207164087437537257/November25201204?authuser=0&authkey=Gv1sRgCOKxot2a2fTtlAE&feat=directlink

Comment: what kind of error are you getting??? I have run them on my system and  they all(`GA_test.py`, `GE_Test.py`, `GP_Test.py`) are showing fine mat-plot plotting in the end.

Comment: @NamitKewat: Try to copy GE_Test.py outside the directory, and run it. Unexpectedly, you will get a different result. The one inside directory show things correctly, but the one outside the directory do it wrong, seems that there is no improvement between generations.
I've also edit the question and attach 2 screenshots there.

Comment: see the output what i am getting..they all are correct??? .http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2409700/geneting_tests.zip

Comment: @NamitKewat: Yes they are correct, thank you for trying. But that's not the problem. The real problem will be occur if you copy /Documents/thesis_program/GE_Test.py into /Documents/GE_Test_Fail.py and change the import part as I describe in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add below mentioned lines to your test files which are going outside of your thesis folder.

`import sys` 
 `sys.path.insert(0,"/path to your thesis folder/thesis_program")`

and maintain everything else; for example in `GE_Test.py`.. .

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/path to your thesis folder/thesis_program")
from utils import execute
from classes import Grammatical_Evolution
```

**EDIT:**

Or use this to make it more dynamic
(caution: don't try to find the path by `os.path.abspath('./thesis_program')` because it may not be always possible that you find your `test_files` and your `thesis_folder` are in the same dir; if you can fix them permanently in your code like above; then you are free to use them from anywhere on your system)

```
import os, sys
lib_path = os.path.abspath('./thesis_program')
sys.path.insert(0,lib_path)
```

Comment: Thank you that's works. But I still can't figure out what's wrong here. I've also edit your question (add an alternative) to make it more dynamic

Comment: according to python docs `sys.path` is a `a list of strings that specifies the search path for modules.` so try to add `print sys.path` in your code to just before and after that addition( `sys.path.insert(0,lib_path)` which works for your code. you can see that python has added your `thesis_program` folder to its look-up locations where it will find for modules.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path

Comment: I have try to use sys.path.append(lib_path) before, and it doesn't work. But your solution sys.path.insert(0,lib_path) works perfectly. I think I need to read more about sys.path. Anyway thanks, you've save my day :)